# Python Algorithm to Improve Efficiency

Tags: python, algorithm

```py
def foo(numbers): 
    result = [] 
    for i in range(len(numbers)): 
        sub = sorted(numbers[i:]) 
        result.append(sub[0]) 
    return result
```

Need to rewrite an asymptotically most efficient implementation of the function foo(numbers) mentioned above. The function must not modify the parameter numbers.

The implementation must be such that a list of numbers with 10^5 elements can be processed in less than a second.

**The testing cases are:**

1. foo(list(range(10**5)))
   print("ok")
2. print(foo([1,2,4,3]))
3. print(foo([8, 7]))
4. print(foo([5]))
5. print(foo([3, 3, 2, 1]))

**Expected results from the testing cases:**

1. ok
2. [1, 2, 3, 3]
3. [7, 7]
4. [5]
5. [1, 1, 1, 1]

**My 1st attempt is using recursive but the code runner bans the sorted function and the code doesn't pass the 10^5 elements test:**

```
def foo(numbers):
if len(numbers) <= 1:
    return [(sorted(numbers))[0]]
else:
    return [(sorted(numbers))[0]] + foo(numbers[1:])
```

**My 2nd attempt is using insertion sort. It pass the 10^5 elements test but it doesn't get all the desired results**

```
def foo(numbers):

    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        num = numbers[i]
        j=i
            
        while j >= 1 and numbers[j-1] > num:
            numbers[j] = numbers[j-1]
            j -= 1
            numbers[j] = num           
    return numbers
```

Comment: Your indentation is clearly wrong; please [edit] to fix it. On the desktop version of this site, paste your code, then select the pasted block and type ctrl-K to correctly format your code with indentations preserved.

Comment: Is there no expected output from the first test case?

Comment: If you want to improve the asymptotic behaviour of an algorithm to make it *optimal*, you generally can't do that by tweaking the code to improve it. Start by understanding what problem the algorithm is meant to solve, then *throw away the suboptimal algorithm entirely* and try to design an optimal algorithm from scratch. So, what problem is the algorithm in your question meant to solve?

Comment: First step is figuring out what the code is doing. To me, it looks like the i'th value in the result is the minimum of the last (N-i) numbers in the input array. Once you have that, writing an O(n) solution is easy.

Answer (score 2):

Solve the problem from last index down to the first one, each time update your current minimum with the current number.

```py
def foo(numbers): 
    result = [] 
    tmp = numbers[::-1]
    mn = tmp[0]
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        mn = min(mn,tmp[i])
        result.append(mn)
    result = result[::-1]
    return result
```

Comment: This does not give the required results

Comment: @OlvinRoght Can you give a counter example please? I tested the method on the provided samples and it gave the exact results

Comment: It does now that you've edited it! Your first post forgot to reverse the list

Comment: I edited it in like 5 minutes, but your comment is way later than the edit !!

Comment: stack**overflow** pages don't refresh dynamically so what I was seeing was your original post. All good now

Comment: Oh thanks for the clarification, and sorry for sounding aggressive.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to fulfil the brief:

```
import time

def foo(numbers): 
    mn = numbers[-1]
    return [mn := min(mn, t) for t in numbers[::-1]][::-1]

s = time.perf_counter()
foo(list(range(10**5)))
e = time.perf_counter()
print(f'Duration: {e-s:.4f}s')
print(foo([1,2,4,3]))
print(foo([8,7]))
print(foo([5]))
print(foo([3,3,2,1]))
```

**Output:**

```
Duration: 0.0190s
[1, 2, 3, 3]
[7, 7]
[5]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
```